# Finding parent of an element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting closest or parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977776/detecting-closest-or-parent-div)

I need some help about finding elements with jquery. As topic hints, i need to find the container of given element. i already have a code like;

```
$('.cancel_button').bind "click", (event) ->
    element = $(this.parentElement)
    ...
    ...
```

But it seems very ugly to me. Cancel `button` is in a `section` element. I wonder if it is possible to do something like

```
$(this).containerElement('section')
```

Comment: It seems ugly because cancel button may exists in a deeper hierarchy.

Comment: It's well worth taking an hour or two to read through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It really only takes that long, and you'll make those hours back within a week. I guarantee you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be looking for [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) or [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest):

```
$(this).parent()

// or

$(this).closest('section')
```

You might even want to combine them, because `closest` will return the *current* element if it matches. So if you had a `div` that was within a `section` that was within a `div`:

```
<div id="outer">
    <section>
        <div id="inner">....</div>
    </section>
</div>
```

...and you wanted to get `outer` when an event occurred on `inner`, it'd be:

```
$(this).parent().closest('div');
```

But when the element you're starting with doesn't match the selector, you don't need it.

Comment: thanks for detailed answer. I think .closest is what im looking for:)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).parent(); // get parent of current object
$(this).closest('.class'); // get closest parent that have class="class"
$(this).closest('section') // get closest parent that is section element
```